# Is it unnecessary to use ehcache over mongodb?

Tags: performance, mongodb, ehcache

1 for indexed object, such as user indexed by Id username
2 simple query, such as search by page, username
3 complex query, tag, geolocation query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, formulate your question more clearly, please.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many factors including your hardware, and your data. However, if all your data fits in ram, mongo will keep it all in ram, so its doubtful.

I've never used ehcache though.